# Isometries of $\left[0,1\right]$ form $\left[-1,2\right]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, set-theory

I am having trouble rationalizing the following scenario:

Given arbitrary real numbers $x,y\in\left[0,1\right]$, an equivalence relation $x\sim y$ is defined if $x-y\in\mathbb{Q}$, such relationship partitions $\left[0,1\right]$ in disjointed equivalence classes, choose one point of each class and construct a set, denoted by $E$. Now consider $A=\{r_1,r_2,\dots\}$ the set of all the rational numbers in the $\left[-1,1\right]$ interval, construct the disjointed collection $\{E_n\}$ where $E_n=\{r_n+x:x\in E\land r_n\in A\}$ where its countable union contains $\left[-1,2\right]$.

This is my understanding so far, every rational number between $0$ and $1$ should be in one equivalence class, because the difference between rational numbers is always rational. Irrational numbers in $\left[0,1\right]$ that are at a rational distance of others should be added to an equivalent class, my first question is if this is enough to claim that $\left[0,1\right]\in E$? For example, what happens to irrational numbers at an irrational distance? If all rationals are represented just by one number, there should be holes in the number line defined by the elements of $E$, isn't it?

On the other hand, if it is true that $E$ contains $\left[0,1\right]$, then I can't understand how the translations $E_n$ by a rational build disjoint sets. Say $E_i=\{\frac{1}{2}+x:x\in E\land \frac{1}{2}\in A\}$ and $E_j=\{\frac{1}{3}+x:x\in E\land \frac{1}{3}\in A\}$ should have a non empty intersection, right?

If all of the above is true then it should be trivial that the countable union of $E_n$ contains $\left[-1,2\right]$

Comment: I suppose you firstly meant to ask if $[0,1]\subset E$. This is clearly false since $E$ contains one representative of each equivalence class formed by $\sim$. In particular, each rational number in $[0,1]$ belongs to the same class, so only one rational number from $[0,1]$ is in $E$.

Comment: It seems like you are looking at the construction of a non-measurable set. In that construction it is never claimed that $[0,1]\subset E$ but rather it is claimed that $[0,1]\subset \bigcup_{k}E_{k}$ which is true.

Comment: That sounded fishy at the start, thanks for the clarification @Manifoldski, quick follow up, are the $E_n$ disjointed?

Comment: Yes, they are disjoint. Assume to the contrary that they are not and you will get a relation: $x + r_{i} = y + r_{j}$ for some $x,y\in E$, and $r_{i},r_{j}$ rational and distinct ($r_{i}\ne r_{j}$). The relation forces $x = y$ (can you see how this follows by definition of $E$?) which contradicts that $r_{i} \ne r_{j}$.

Comment: Yes! Had to stretch my legs for that one, but now the statement that you said before @Manifoldski, that the countable union span $[0,1]$, is it because we are feeling the rational gaps with the translation of rationals? I am trying to paint a picture in my head but it maybe that is not the way to go.

Comment: Yes, that correct. By adding the rational numbers in $[-1,1]$ to an element $x\in E$ we are guaranteed to hit all numbers a rational distance away from $x$ in $[0,1]$. Doing this for all elements $x\in E$ we are guaranteed to cover $[0,1]$ because of the definition of $E$. Now,  we choose the interval $[-1,1]$ for the rationals because, if say $0\in E$ then we need to add all rationals in $[0,1]$ to $0$ to recover what was lost. On the other hand if $1\in E$ then we need to add all rationals in $[-1,0]$ to $1$. (cont...)

Comment: So by adding all rationals in $[−1,1]$ to $x\in E$ we have enough rational numbers to cover all $y$ with $x\leq y\leq 1$ and all $z$ with $0\leq z\leq x$ where $y$ and $z$ are rational distances from $x$.